# asp classic Math.abs issue

Tags: asp.net, math

I have a 'weeks' variable in application:

Math.abs(var_weeks / ONE_WEEK);

and it returns "37.3857142857143 weeks"

How can i cut this value to "37.3 weeks" ?

I need to leave just one number after comma.
Thanks!

Comment: You're actually asking how to print a number with fewer decimal places.

Comment: To leave one number after comma i have made the next:

       var weeks
       // it returns 5.123123 for example
       
        var weeksnum = weeks * 10;
       // it returns 51.23123
        
       var weeksfinal = Math.round(weeksnum)/10;
       // it returns 512/10 - 51.2

Comment: @Serhiog.Lazin, feel free to write your own solution as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

To leave one number after comma i have made the next:

```
   var weeks
   // it returns 5.123123 for example

    var weeksnum = weeks * 10;
   // it returns 51.23123

   var weeksfinal = Math.round(weeksnum)/10;
   // it returns 512/10 - 51.2
```